# Save a date from NSDate() without +0000 at the end in CoreData

Tags: ios, date, core-data, swift, tableview

I searched the posts but didn't find something I could use...

What I try to do is: I want to save a date in CoreData (as an NSDate) but without the timezone identifier like +0000. The reason for that is, I use the date later as sorting path / title in a TableView and it just looks not so nice with the +0000 at the end. 
I can not convert the date from CoreData as I use the "titleForHeader" function together with the NSFetchedResultsController, so I have no chance to convert that beforehand...
Or is it even possible to save the NSDate with a format like "dd-MM-yyyy / HH:mm" but still as NSDate() ?
I want do all this in Swift!

Thanks for any help...

Comment: `NSDate` doesn't include timezone information to begin with. What exactly are you trying to do, format a `NSDate` to a string?

Comment: Like others have said. `NSDate` doesn't have any time zone information. In fact it doesn't have any concept of days, months, or years. Or anything like that. It is purely a single point in time. When you print it out your computer will render it into a string using your current calendar and then display that string.

Answer (score 3):

NSDate doesn't contain any timezone information, you need to save the NSDate in Core Data then use an NSDateFormatter to format it for display.

Answer (score 1):

It's no possible to save a NSDate without that. Only if your are going to save as an NSString and in that case you can use something like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

OR

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
```

Then save the string as:

```
[dateFormatter stringFromDate:YOUR_NSDATE_VAR];
```

Cheers.

Comment: Yes I know how to format that but I was just looking for a solution to do it the way I described above, it seems I have to refactor my whole code to get that done... Thanks guys...

Comment: *"It's no possible to save a NSDate without that..."* Of course it is, because that is not part of the NSDate. It's something that only shows up when formatting the date, as you described. The NSDate never contains that.

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me:

```
 NSDate *date = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MaxDate"];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat =@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringFromDate];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    NSString *newDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
    NSLog(@"%@", newDateString);
```

Comment: @EricAya. Neglecting your comment.